# Adding zero to part of string using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have SNMP outputs like:

```
IP-MIB::ipNetToMediaPhysAddress.5122.192.19.3.25 = STRING: 34:8:4:56:f4:70
```

As you can see mac-address output is incorrect, and i fix it with sed:

```
echo IP-MIB::ipNetToMediaPhysAddress.5122.192.19.3.25 = STRING: 34:8:4:56:f4:70  |
sed -e 's/\b\(\w\)\b/0\1/g'
```

Output:

```
IP-MIB::ipNetToMediaPhysAddress.5122.192.19.03.25 = STRING: 34:08:04:56:f4:70
```

It fixes address but changes IP as well from 192.19.3.25 to 192.19.03.25. How can I avoid it and force to perform sed only after `STRING:` or only after last space in the string ?

Answer (score 4):

The MAC address is colon-separated.  You can use that to limit the substitutions.  This will perform the substitutions that you are interested in but only if the word character is next to a colon:

```
sed -e 's/\b\w:/0&/g; s/:\(\w\)\b/:0\1/g'
```

For example:

```
$ echo IP-MIB::ipNetToMediaPhysAddress.5122.192.19.3.25 = STRING: 34:8:4:56:f4:70  | sed -e 's/\b\w:/0&/g; s/:\(\w\)\b/:0\1/g'
IP-MIB::ipNetToMediaPhysAddress.5122.192.19.3.25 = STRING: 34:08:04:56:f4:70
```

#### How it works

- `s/\b\w:/0&/g`

  This performs the substitution if the word character is preceded by a word break, `\b`, and followed by a colon.  Since we just need to put a zero in front of the entire matched text, not just some section of it, we can omit the parens and just use `&` to copy the matched text.
- `s/:\(\w\)\b/:0\1/g`

  If there are any remaining substitutions that need to be done where the word character is preceded by a colon and followed by a word break, this does them.

Note: We are using GNU extensions that may not be portable.

Answer (score 0):

Another way with sed if the MAC address is at end of line

```
echo IP-MIB::ipNetToMediaPhysAddress.5122.192.19.3.25 = STRING: 4:8:d:56:f4:7 |
sed -E '
s/$/:/
:A
s/([^[:xdigit:]])([[:xdigit:]]:)/\10\2/
tA
s/:$//'
```